# how to get the declaration of a list done during the unnesting recursively?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have been getting my head around to do the recursion **without using any global variable**. If am passing the lists the lists of lists ... and resultantly, i should have all the elements from the input in a single list. The problem is every time i call the function the list is declared from the start.

```
    def unnest (alist):  
        List_ = list()

        for elements in alist: 
            if type(elements) == list: 
                unnest(elements)
            else: 
                List_.append(elements)
        return List_
    if __name__=='__main__':
        unnest([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]])
```

Comment: my goal is to turn the given input list into
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

Comment: See [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/4014959) for generator solutions.

Comment: Champion! thanks mate

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the returned `List_`, in subsequent calls, and extend the current list:

```
def recursion (alist):
    List_ = list()

    for elements in alist:
        if type(elements) == list:
            List_.extend(recursion(elements))  # extend list with recursive call
        else:
            List_.append(elements)  # just add "leaf" element
    return List_

if __name__=='__main__':
    z=recursion([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]])
    print(z)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: you did not even use the return value in the first place, I just did not see the line (since it was just before the main). I added another one it works because the second one is never reached.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, There are inbuilt module support for making flattern.

```
In [47]: from compiler.ast import flatten
In [48]: lst = [1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]]
In [49]: flatten(lst)
Out[49]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Recursion method,

```
def flatern(l,ml):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            flatern(i,ml)
        else:
            ml.append(i)
    return ml
```

**Result**

```
In [52]: flatern(lst,[])
Out[52]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: solves this particular problem, nice idea: +1. But I think the OP idea was to create a recursion example. You just killed it for him :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are exactly right. Updated my answer with recursion method also.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass an accumulator list to the recursive bit of your computation:

```
def flatten(xs):
    accum = []
    def rec(xs):
        for x in xs:
            if isinstanceof(x, list):
                rec(x)
            else:
                accum.append(x)
    rec(xs)
    return accum
```

then use `flatten` instead of `rec`:

```
flatten([1,2,[3,4,[5,6,7]]])
```

Comment: see my edits, but in any case, I disagree that my code is unreadable; any code can get unreadable quickly if you're not careful

Comment: Looks much better now! All I was pointing out was that mutating function arguments while recursing, and using that as a sort of *store* for final results can quickly grow unreadable (even though it might be fully readable now)

Answer (score 1):

Your code fixed:
You have to append the next recursion level, so the return of a deeper recursion is appended all the way to the top level

```
def unnest (alist):  
    List_ = list()

    for elements in alist: 
        if type(elements) == list: 
            List_.extend(unnest(elements))
        else: 
            List_.append(elements)


    return List_

unnest([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]])
```

returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: this will get slow with larger lists

Comment: `List_ = List_ + (unnest(elements))` is really sub-optimal because it destroys previous ref of `List_` to create another bigger one each time. `List_ += unnest(elements)` is better (or use `extend`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner function which will do the recursion. This has several adventages:

- The function signature will not change
- No use of global variables
- You will not create a new list each recursion call (memory friendly)

---

```
def flatten(old_list):    
    def flattenA(old_list,new_list):
        for item in old_list: 
            if isinstance(item,list):
                flattenA(item , new_list)
            else: 
                new_list.append(item)
        return new_list
    return flattenA(old_list,[])

if __name__=='__main__':
    print( flatten([1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]]) )
# prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=[1,2,[3,4,5,[6,7,[8,9,[10,11,[12,[13,[14]]]]]]]]
l=[]
  def recursion(list1,l):
      for i in list1:
          if type(i) is list:
             recursion(i,l)
          else:
             l.append(i)

 recursion(list1,l)
 print(l)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```